# Estimate visible bounds of webcam using diagonal fov

Tags: math, geometry, webcam, trigonometry, frustum

I'm using a Logitech C920 webcam [(specs here)](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28927/~/c920-technical-specifications) and I need to estimate the visible bounds of it before installing it at the user place.

I see that it has a Diagonal FOV of 78°. So, following the math [described here](http://vrguy.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/converting-diagonal-field-of-view-and.html) we have:

[image: formulas]

Where H is the vertical Fov, W is the horizontal Fov, D is the diagonal Fov and the aspect ratio is r. 
Considering an aspect ratio of 16/9, that gives me approx. W = 67.9829  and H = 38.2403

So I create a frustum using W and H.

The problem is: a slice of this frustum isn't 16:9. Is it due because of the numeric approximations or I'm doing something else wrong?

Does the camera crop a bigger image?

How can I compute effectively what will be the visible frustum?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The formulae you have are for distances, not for angles. You would need to calculate the distance using tangens:

```
D = 2 * tan(diagonalFov / 2)
```

Then you can go ahead with your formula. `H` and `W` will again be distance values. If you need the according angles, you can use arc tan:

```
verticalFov = 2 * arc tan (H / 2)
horizontalFov = 2 * arc tan (W / 2)
```

For your values, you'll get

```
verticalFov = 43.3067°
horizontalFov = 70.428°
```